# I am unable to find callback methods in .NET core 2.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am Ruby on Rails developer. Rails provide callback methods (May be it has some other name in .net world). Callbacks are defined in the models. they are invoked as soon as you trigger those specific actions. e.g. after_save, after_create, before_save, after_update etc etc.

I am trying to achieve similar functionality in .Net core 2.0.

Here is my User model

```
public class User : BaseModel
{

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string TempToken { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to create a unique token for each user. So am trying to implement a method which will be triggered as soon as a new user is created.

I can achieve this in the controller but as per MVC pattern, it should be implemented in Model.

Thanks

Comment: What does Rails have to do with .NET?  What do these callbacks *do*?  What actual functionality are you trying to implement?  Have you started with some introductory tutorials on .NET Core?

Comment: @david and others who have downvoted - this guy is obviously new why don't you help him.  His question is clear enough to warrant a working example which I will write when I have a moment.

Comment: I wish someone must have read the question. It seems pretty straight forward to me. are there any callbacks in .net.

Comment: @AjitSingh: That depends on what you mean by "callbacks".  Just a reference to a method to be invoked at a later time?  Some structure for invoking asynchronous operations and responding to their results?  A specific set of functionality in Rails with which .NET programmers may not be familiar?  Something else?  Please clarify specifically what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to create after save callback. So anytime I save any record.. this method will trigger automatically. e.g. I want to send an email eveytime a user update his profile. so controller will call user.save and an after save callback will trigger which will send an email.

Comment: @AjitSingh: That doesn't sound like a "callback".  In your code where you perform the save operation, the very next thing would be to perform your email operation.  Just call one and then call the other.  They'll execute in the order in which they're called.  Perhaps you might be thinking of raising an event and responding to that event?  Some sort of publish/subscribe pattern?  From the description it sounds like you just want to call some code, and then call other code.  So it's not clear why you can't do that directly.  Perhaps you can provide a code example to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: may be it is called something else in .NET. But here is something I do in Rails. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: @AjitSingh: The design appears to be very different between these frameworks, so any direct correlation between the two is unlikely.  Don't try to "do what Rails does".  Instead, focus on the business functionality you're looking to implement in your ASP.NET Core MVC app.  Start building your app using what you learn from relevant tutorials and examples.  When you build the feature for saving your model to the database, *then* consider how you would add this email functionality. It's likely that your controller is just going to invoke two operations. One to save, and then one to send an email.

Comment: @David Your advice has little practical value when you dont know what you dont know. Also, his question is "...is there something similar in .net" not "How do I learn .net". Based on this text "Callbacks are methods that get called at certain moments..." found on the link the OP provided, it appears he may be looking for something like an event. "From the description it sounds like you just want to call some code, and then call other code." It does not appear that way at all.  A callback is specific pattern, perhaps not the one he wants, but very different from placing one line after another.

Comment: @Sam: And if that is indeed what the OP is asking, that's *great*. He can clarify that and the community is more likely to provide a clear and helpful answer. Currently it reads (to me at least) less like the OP is asking about patterns and more like the OP has a specific piece of functionality to achieve (sending an email after saving data), understands how to do it in one framework, and is trying to find direct feature parity in another vastly different framework. It would be good if the OP could clarify, is he asking how to implement a pub/sub pattern or how to send an email after saving?

Comment: @AjitSingh: Would you be able to provide clarity (in an edit to the question) regarding this ongoing conversation in the comments?  What *specifically* are you asking here?  Is there a general pattern you're looking to implement in your ASP.NET Core MVC application?  Or is there a specific piece of functionality and, while you may have thought you had to do it one way, you're really just asking how it would simply be done?

Comment: @david I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @AjitSingh: The framework doesn’t really have anything built in for this, at least not that same structure.  Normally in .NET (and it’s something that can be debated by purists at length, but it is what it is) the models come across as fairly anemic, particularly when interacting with the persistence layer. The controller would normally invoke the data context or unit of work or repository, send it the model to persist, and dispose of it. So the model doesn’t “know” it’s being persisted. From that, there are a variety of approaches you can take to do this, all based on personal preference.

Comment: @AjitSingh: I guess in short... There is no framework-native analog for this.  So it’s up to you how you’d choose to architect it.  The controller can can the follow-up operation, the persistence layer can do it transparently to the controller, the operation could be obscured behind the model and it can internally invoke the operation under some condition, a repository can raise custom events and some other component of yours can be responsible to subscribe to those events, etc., etc.

Comment: @David "... There is no framework-native analog for this."  Sure there is David.  I believe the models the OP describes are just raising events as we do in C#.  As you mention .net isn't really built to work that way but it is entirely feasible to build as OP suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the first thing about Ruby but I'm guessing the callbacks on the models are the equivalent of events in c#.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CustomerRepository repo = new CustomerRepository();

        // wire up the BeforeSave event as needed
        repo.BeforeSave += c => Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} will be saved...", c.Name);

        // wire up the AfterSave event to send an email or whatever you need
        repo.AfterSave += c => Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} was saved sucessfully.", c.Name);  

        // create a new customer
        Customer cust = new Customer { ID = 1, Name = "Sam" };

        // save the customer which will fire the before/after events
        repo.Save(cust);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class CustomerRepository 
{
    public event Action<Customer> BeforeSave;
    public event Action<Customer> AfterSave;

    public virtual void Save(Customer customer)
    {
        // Invoke the before save event on the repo
        BeforeSave?.Invoke(customer);

        // do some save stuff
        Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} is being saved...", customer.Name);

        // Invoke the after save event
        AfterSave?.Invoke(customer);
    }
}


public class Customer 
{
    // Put events here or in a base class if you wish, 
    // just as is shown in the repository class 
    // but that is probably not a good design

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get what is up with this question. It's perfectly valid. Also @Sam provided one possibly approach. 
The problem is not that Ajit does not know about .NET mechanics, but that others refuse to care about how Ruby on Rails (and ActiveRecord specifically) works and translates to .NET.
@Ajit, please correct me if I am on the wrong track here.
What I write further down already exists in different flavors. You might want to look into Entity-Framework and others. I use the code to explain the concept.

Looking at the Active-Record pages, there is this example:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :login, :email, presence: true

  before_create do
    self.name = login.capitalize if name.blank?
  end
end
```

So `ApplicationRecord`is a base-class. Any class deriving from this class will have methods like `create`, `delete` and alike. 
It's *these* methods calling what you (and the ActiveRecord documentation) are referring to as "Callback".

One possible approach would be to implement this yourself.

First create a baseclass.

```
public class ActiveRecord
{
  public virtual void Create() 
  {
    // call the BeforeCreate-"Callback"
    this.BeforeCreate();

    // do what this method has to do
    // you can override this method in any deriving class
  }
  protected virtual void BeforeCreate()
  {
  }
}
```

Then go on write your classes inheriting from this class.

```
public class User:ActiveRecord
{
  public Guid Id{get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  protected override void BeforeCreate()
  {
    if(this.Id==null || this.Id == Guid.Empty)
    {
      this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
      Console.WriteLine($"Created new Guid for User:{this.Id}");
    }
  }
}
```

When you now write code like this, you will have your `BeforeCreate` method being called.

```
public static void Main()
{
  User myUser = new User();
  myUser.Create();
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I hope this is helpful.
You could also look for .NET implementations of the ActiveRecord-Pattern since you seem to be familiar with it.
Example: https://github.com/castleproject/ActiveRecord

Cheers,

Kristof

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking. Is there a way to generate beforeCreate or aftercreate. Thanks a lot